# Trying to fetch database table according to selected option

Tags: php, mysqli

I am newbie in programming. i am making a online prize bond wallet system, i used select option to select the bond and then search in database.

I am getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\PBWS\searchi.php on
>   line 37
>
> Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PBWS\searchi.php on line 37
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PBWS\searchi.php on line 39

```
<?php

include_once('database.php');

    if(isset($_GET['file_name']))
    $name = $_GET['file_name'];
    if ($_GET['value'] == 'bond_100'){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bond_100` WHERE `file_name` = $name ";
}

    elseif ($_GET['value'] == 'bond_200'){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bond_200` WHERE `file_name` = $name";
}

    elseif ($_GET['value'] == 'bond_1500'){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bond_1500` WHERE `file_name` = $name ";
}
    elseif ($_GET['value'] == 'bond_15000'){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bond_15000` WHERE `file_name` = $name ";
}
    elseif ($_GET['value'] == 'bond_750'){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bond_750` WHERE `file_name` = $name "; 
}   
    elseif ($_GET['value'] == 'bond_7500'){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bond_7500` WHERE `file_name` = $name ";
}
    elseif ($_GET['value'] == 'bond_40000'){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bond_40000` WHERE `file_name` = $name ";

}   $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

     if($row>0){
        echo $row["file_name"];
    } else{
        echo "nothing found";
}
```

Comment: iainn - no he doesn't. from php.net - mixed `mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add these lines :

```
echo 'Value : ', $_GET['value'];
die();
```

Since your thread of `else if` blocks is followed by no `else` block to handle the case where none of them is executed, your script receiving an incorrect value for `$_GET['value']` or no value at all would result in `$sql` to not exist when you try to execute your query, which would explain both the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

None of your if or else if statements are ever true! Therefore $sql is never defined!

Find out why! `var_dump($_GET);` and see what you get!